# How to highlight when path exactly match '/'?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

How to highlight when path exactly match `'/'`?

Right now even when I go to **Page 2**, the link **Home** is still highlight.

<kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gpqdIVARXDMcUBYd5tfg?p=preview)</kbd>

```
.active { color: red; }

<a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/">Home</a>
<a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/page2">Page 2</a>
```

routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component },

  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

I tried to change to `path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'`, but it does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html